# Calling PHP class in C#

Tags: c#, php, wpf

Before I get into my question, note that I'm a beginner when it comes to c# so bare with me please.

As for an assignment I have to make my PHP project into an executable. Now I've tried the compilers but with little to no success. The idea behind it is to load an API where you receive orders from various clients and the PHP file that I've written filters all the order id's out that you don't want to see and save desired info into an XML file.

Is there a way to either run a php file in your C# WPF or call the PHP class methods in your C# application?

Code looks as followed:

```
<?php
class classified_API {
    // Properties
    private $classified_client;
    // Constructor 
    public function __construct($_classified_client){ 

        $this->classified_client = $_classified_client;    
        if (SHOW_DEBUG_INFO == 'true') {
            echo "<hr>CLIENT ID: ".$this->classified->getClientId()."<br>"; 
            echo "<hr>CLIENT SECRET: ".$this->classified->getClientSecret()."<br>"; 
            echo "<hr>CLIENT BEARER TOKEN: ".$this->classified->getBearerToken()."<br>"; 
        }
        //  echo 'The class "' . __CLASS__ . '" was initiated!<br>';
    }
}  // Class consists more code, but it's too much to post
```

The PHP project looks like this:

[image]

The WPF display:

[image]

Is there a way to connect the API php page to the C# project so I can bring changes to the saved XML documents?

Comment: Is the PHP deployed to a website? If so, just call the API using HttpClient methods from C#. If not, you can run an executable using Process classes

Comment: if the PHP is part of a web-based API then your C# code can just make a HTTP request to it, like any other API. The language the API is implemented in is entirely irrelevant (which is one of the main reasons the web is so successful!), because all your C# has to deal with is a HTTP request and response - the communication is done using a generic data interchange protocol which both sides can understand.